# Running ColdFusion as a specific user

Tags: coldfusion

On [this page](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/running-coldfusion-specific-user.html), it talks about Windows NT, 2000, XP and 2003.  Fortunately, I have a Windows 7 machine.

The very first line says:

> In User Manager for Domains, create a local user for the ColdFusion
>   service to log in as.

I don't see a "User Manager for Domains", so do they mean just "Add a new user"?

If it DOES mean that, can I use my own user account as the ColdFusion user, or should I specifically create a new account just for ColdFusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating a domain account it has to be created ON the domain - using user manager for domains connected to your domain controllers. If that's what you need then a sys admin has to help.

If you are doing a "local" user on a windows 7 I always end up hunting around for the right view of user manager before I get it right :)  Here are the steps that I use:

1. Search from start and open the "user accounts" cpl.
2. Click on "Manage User Accounts"
3. Click on the "advanced" tab
4. Click on the "advanced" buttton.

This takes me to the mmc-like view of users that I'm accustomed to where I can add a user, change membership, set passwords etc.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use your own username or you can create one for CF to run as.  Creating a user to run CF as probably more closely replicates your production environment ( an assumption ) so if production for example writes to a UNC path the coldfusion user must have acces.  You could
Mimic this locally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either an account local to the OS where ColdFusion is running, or a domain account if the OS is joined to a domain.  In your case, you can just create a local user on your Windows 7 OS and run the ColdFusion Application Service as that user.  The user account will need access to ColdFusion's installation folder, as well as read access to the webroot.

The whole idea is to run the ColdFusion service as a user with the minimum privileges necessary to handle requests and prevent access to other resources in the event of a data breach or remote code execution (e.g. someone exploits an upload form and manages to get their own CF code to run on your server; it's not pretty but can be somewhat restricted by running the CF service under a user account with restricted access).

As someone else mentioned, if CF needs access to other network resources, the user account will need to be granted access to those resources as well (either by using a domain account or having a local account with the same username and password on the remote system).

Answer (score 1):

Just did this on Windows 2008 R2 with CF 10. The trick was to change the ownership of the c:\windows and c:\windows\system32 directories as outlined here.

[change ownership from trustedInstaller](http://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-restore-trustedinstaller-as-default-owner-of-a-file-or-folder-in-windows/)

Comment: You should add some data from the link to your answer. Do not solely rely on the link.

Comment: Taking ownership of a file or folder is simple, right click - properties - security - advanced - ownership tab - edit...the trick to changing it back, since trustedinstaller is not listed, is to add it in with, NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller so you can choose it as the owner.